# Is there anything wrong with nested Views in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-design, view

Is there anything wrong with having one view reference another view? For example, say I have a 
users table

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Then for the sake of argument a view that just shows all users

```
CREATE VIEW all_users AS SELECT * FROM users
```

And then a view that just returns their **first_name** and **last_name**

```
CREATE VIEW full_names AS SELECT first_name, last_name FROM all_users
```

Are there performance issue with basing one view off another? Let's also pretend this is the simplest of examples and a real world scenario would be much more complex, but the same general concept of basing one view of another view.

Comment: typically the perf is worse than if you do Select directly against the table but you're better off trying it and seeing if it acceptable for your use case.

Comment: remove semicolon after PRIMARY KEY (id). Also change OT NULL by NOT NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the [ALGORITHM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/view-algorithms.html) used. TEMPTABLE can be pretty expensive while MERGE should be the same as using the table directly so no loss there.

Answer (score 1):

And for your example is the same:

```
mysql> explain select * from users;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra               |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | system | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    0 | const row not found |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> explain select * from all_users;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra               |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | system | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    0 | const row not found |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select * from full_names ;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra               |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | system | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    0 | const row not found |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```